# understanding the benefit direct-address tables

Tags: algorithm, search, data-structures

I am struggling with the understanding of direct-address table. Based on the image below (source: Cormer's Introduction to Algorithms), you define a large array to store objects in it. A must is that one of the fields of stored objects is of type integer. That integer defines the position in the array of objects. It is named key here.

So if you want to perform a search or delete you can only do so with a key(but not satellite data). There is no way of performing a search on the satellite data. I am not really seeing the benefit of this structure, since it limits you to only search based on keys, which are always integers and not the actual satellite data of interest. In order for this data structure to be useful, there needs to be a way to compute key from satellite data, right?

[image]

Comment: The key can be anything, and does not have to be an integer. It does have to have a hash code though. The "satelite" data is not searchable by design, it is implementation of a `map:key->value`, where you can access by `key` fast, but not by `value` (also, you can have multiple identical values, but not keys in `map`, you can have both in `multimap`. If you do need access both, you will need an implementation of bidirectional map, which is a different data structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every data structure is built for a particular purpose allowing advantages in case of some operations while at the same time penalising others.

Direct address table allows for quick access for value given the key or in other words a mapping from domain of keys to range of values(or content). The key can be anything as mentioned in the comment but has to "hashable" .

It can serve many important purposes for example in memory translation where you want to translate key value( offset ) into actual address quickly. This would allow one to work with the tags easily and in case if there is a change(new addresses replacing old ones) one has to simply modify the translation mechanism ie. the mapping table(based on direct address table) .

There can be several other situations where this can be found useful.